# creating combined views inside a view

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uibezierpath

I am trying to create a circular UIView with a hole in the middle and then place that view combined with the top of another view . However I am not sure that I am going about it the right way

Here is what I am trying to do (as the top circles show here in sketch): [image]

So far this is is how I was going about it in playground:

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
import CoreGraphics


extension UIColor {
    static func getRandomColor() -> UIColor {
        //Generate between 0 to 1
        let red:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let green:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())
        let blue:CGFloat = CGFloat(drand48())

        return UIColor(red:red, green: green, blue: blue, alpha: 1.0)
    }
}

func makeCircularView(x: Int = 0 , y : Int = 0 , width: Double, height : Int, color: UIColor) -> UIView {
    let view : UIView = UIView(frame:CGRect(x: x, y: y, width: Int(width), height: height))
    view.alpha = 0.5
    view.layer.cornerRadius = view.bounds.size.width / 2
    view.backgroundColor = color
    view.layer.masksToBounds = true
    return view
}



let uiView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500))
uiView.backgroundColor = .red

uiView.clipsToBounds = true
uiView.layer.shadowRadius
uiView.layer.cornerRadius = 5
uiView



let cir : UIView
let circle2 : UIView
cir = makeCircularView(width : 30 , height : 30, color: UIColor.gray)
circle2 = makeCircularView( x:  Int(7.5) , y : Int(7.5), width: 15, height: 15, color: UIColor.clear)

cir.addSubview(circle2)
uiView.addSubview(cir)


cir.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.topAnchor, constant: -20).isActive = true
cir.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: uiView.leadingAnchor, constant: -10).isActive = true
```

Comment: did you get solution ?

Comment: Not yet, I am going to try tonight, and I'll then update you ...

Comment: i just done this thing

Comment: @HimanshuMoradiya are you able to post up your code ?

Comment: i just made one .xib file and just create file file that containts your 2 view

Answer (score 0):

Use this func and pass the corner views in it.

```
func createView(_ myview : UIView)  {
        myview.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        myview.layer.cornerRadius = myview.frame.width/2 // assuming myview is squre


        myview.layer.borderColor = UIColor.white.cgColor
        myview.layer.borderWidth = 4
    }
```

**Output**

[image]

> Edit

You can do anyone of below, for integrated image

1. Use [PaintCode](https://www.paintcodeapp.com/), It automatically do layer coding for you. (You can use trial version for 5 days).
2. Ask your designer to get that particular Integrated Image, use this image in `UIImageview`

Comment: IS there any way to combine views if one view is outside of another slightly ? like design above